# Proof of a simple inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove the following:$$|e^{-i\left<x\mid h\right>}-1|\leq|\left<x\mid h\right>|$$
Where $x,h\in \mathbb{R^n}$, and $\left<\,\cdot\mid\cdot\,\right>$ is the standard inner product.

It looks like a beginning of Taylor series but I can't see how to get the inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually have to prove that for a real number $t$, $|e^{it}-1|\leqslant |t|$. To see that, write 
$$e^{it}-1=\int_0^tie^{is}ds,$$
then use triangle inequality and the fact that $|ie^{is}|\leqslant 1$.

Comment: Nothing to do with Taylor series then...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The inequality
$$
|e^{i \varphi} - 1| \leqslant |\varphi|
$$
simply states that the length of an arc in a unit circle is greater or equal to the length of the chord with the same endpoints. It is a well known fact )